# attachEvent/for=".." event=".." equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to replace `attachEvent` in Internet Explorer Javascript.

```
ptIn = document.Form1.pt;
if (ptIn.attachEvent){
        ptIn.attachEvent("BeforeContextMenu", pivotBeforeContextMenu);
        ptIn.attachEvent("CommandExecute", pivotCommandExecute);
    }else{
        alert("Running IE11 or IE9");
        ptIn.addEventListener("BeforeContextMenu(ix, iy, mnu, cancel)", pivotBeforeContextMenu,false);  
        ptIn.addEventListener("CommandExecute(vCommand, fSucceeded)", pivotCommandExecute,false);
        ptIn.addEventListener("BeforeContextMenu", pivotBeforeContextMenu,false);  
        ptIn.addEventListener("CommandExecute", pivotCommandExecute,false);
        ptIn.BeforeContextMenu = pivotBeforeContextMenu;
        ptIn.CommandExecute = pivotCommandExecute;
    }
```

I even tried naming the functions `pt_BeforeContextMenu`.

The only thing that does work is making a script tag like : `<script language="javascript" event="BeforeContextMenu(ix, iy, mnu, cancel)" for="pt">`

Is there better way to accomplish attaching a function to an event?

Notes:

`ptIn.attachEvent(....)` works, but no longer in IE11.

Event I am trying to use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa193082(v=office.11).aspx

```
function pivotBeforeContextMenu(iX, iY, mnu, fCancel){ //does stuff }
function pivotCommandExecute(vCommand, fSucceeded){ //does stuff }
```

Comment: Don't try to sniff for browser versions. Just detect if the browser has an addEventListener method.

Comment: I would just switch the if conditions around, and not check IE version at all. If addEventListener exists, use it, else, use attachEvent.

Comment: As @Quentin states - feature detection rather than browser detection is best practice.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many addEventListener polyfills available on the net.

Comment: @epascarello But I'm trying to make it work in a newer browser. Don't pollyfills just allow old browsers to use a replicated modern browser feature?

Comment: @Hillboy `if (element.addEventListener) {/***/} else if (element.attachEvent) {/***/}` is always best.